# Get all IDs of selected/highlighted DIVs

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html

I may be going in the completely wrong direction with what I'm trying to do, so I wanted to ask for help.

*Background / Overview*

I need to display a paragraph of text and allow a user to select one or more words from the paragraph and save their highlighted text to a database, for just their profile.  Actually, hat selection of text will eventually be (1) stored with the highlight AND (2) linked up to another set of highlighted text from another paragraph (basically, I'm tying a phrase from one source to a reference source)

*What I've tried...*

I have tried to put each word of the paragraph into a DIV (and a unique ID) with each DIV set to float left, so that the display looks okay.

```
<style>
div { float: left}
</style>
```

and...using an example:

```
<div id="GEN_1_1">
  <div id="GEN_1_1_1">In</div>
  <div id="GEN_1_1_2">the</div>
  <div id="GEN_1_1_3">beginning</div> 
  <div id="GEN_1_1_4">God</div> 
  <div id="GEN_1_1_5">created</div> 
  <div id="GEN_1_1_6">the</div> 
  <div id="GEN_1_1_7">heaven</div> 
  <div id="GEN_1_1_8">and</div> 
  <div id="GEN_1_1_9">the</div> 
  <div id="GEN_1_1_10">earth</div>.
</div>
```

Which looks like: **In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.** (minus the bold)

So far, I have used the

```
 window.getSelection()
```

function to determine/grab the words that have been highlighted.

I then tried using this:

```
if (window.getSelection) 
{ 
  selected_len = window.getSelection().toString().length;

  if (window.getSelection().toString().length>0) 
  { 
    div_id = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer.parentNode.id; 
  } 
}
```

to get the ID's for each DIV selected, **BUT** I only get a single DIV ID returned right now.

***Help Request*:**

Is there are slick way to get the ID for each DIV selected and put it into an Array, so that I can construct a SQL query to put it into the database (the query is easy)?  The selected words could total up to several hundred, if not a thousand words, so I need to make sure the solution will work with a ton of words selected.

Comment: a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be better.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** [JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/29/)

I modified the code again. See if it works for you now.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(document).on('mouseup keyup', '.checked', function () {
    console.log(window.getSelection());
    if (window.getSelection().toString().length>0) {
        var count = window.getSelection();
        var arr = [];
        $('.checked span').each(function(){
            var span  = $(this)[0];
            var isT = window.getSelection().containsNode(span, true);
            if(isT){
                arr.push($(this).attr('id'));
            }
        });
        console.log(arr,count.toString());
        alert(arr);
        alert(count.toString());
       }
    });
});
```

I created a fiddle for solution. Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/18/

Also, I used `span` instead of `div` for the text selection. I hope that won't be an issue for you. So the code works as you want. It will return the id of the parent span in which text is selected. You can modify it to save the ID into array or as per your needs.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(document).on('mouseup', '.checked', function () {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        var i = getSelectionParentElement();
        console.log(i);
        alert('parent selected:  ' + i.id);
    }
});
});

function getSelectionParentElement() {
    var parent = null, selection;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        selection = window.getSelection();
       if (selection.rangeCount) {
           parent = selection.getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer;
         if (parent.nodeType != 1) {
             parent = parent.parentNode;
          }
        }
    } else if ((selection = document.selection) && selection.type != "Control") {
    parent = selection.createRange().parentElement();
   }
 return parent;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for creating a jsfiddle - I appreciate your help so far.  When I try to select multiple words and then do a mouseup, the alert box just says "parent selected:  ", with no ids listed.  If, however, I just click on/within a single word (without highlighting), the alert message does indeed give the id of the span containing the click-on word.  Like I mentioned in my original post, though.  I need the user to be able to highlight/select multiple words at a single time (maybe hundreds of words at one go) and have all of the ids be captured somehow.

Comment: Sorry for the delay...busy week.  So, when I test this new code, it still only works for a single word at a time, being selected. http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/51/ . When I select "The Quick Brown" and mouseup, the alert says only 'parent selected:'.  I need it to show me all of the ids of the selected 3 words.

Comment: @user3567293 I think the updated link was not clear in the post. So I updated the new link where the code is working as per your question. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/29/